# Is it possible to accept all "Fix-It" suggestions in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Is it possible to accept all "Fix-It" suggestions in Xcode 8 at one time?

Comment: Some of the fix it suggestions lead to new fix its so I find myself have to use Editor->Fix All in Scope several times in a row - it's a handy key sequence to commit to memory.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably use that instead then.

Comment: @HAS That question is posed the same, but doesn't have an answer that really answers the original question.

Comment: Yeah because the aber to your question is "No.".